# drop_na( ) cannot work on POSIX-lt object

Tags: r, tidyr, posixlt

According to the title, I make a simple example to test `drop_na {tidyr}` :

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# (1.) produce a dataset with two POSIX type "ct" and "lt"

data <- data.frame(n = 1:5)
data$ct <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time() + rnorm(5) * 1000)
data$lt <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time() + rnorm(5) * 1000)
str(data)

# $ n : int  1 2 3 4 5
# $ ct: POSIXct, format: "2018-10-07 03:02:28" ...
# $ lt: POSIXlt, format: "2018-10-07 02:37:26" ...


# (2.) assign the third values of "ct" and "lt" to NA

data[3, c("ct", "lt")] <- NA


# (3.) use different function to remove rows with NA

data %>% is.na()               # identify NAs in both "ct" and "lt"
data %>% drop_na('ct')         # drop NA from "ct"
data %>% drop_na('lt')         # NOT drop NA from "lt"
data[c(1, 2)] %>% na.omit()    # drop NA from "ct"
data[c(1, 3)] %>% na.omit()    # NOT drop NA from "lt"
```

From the conclusion above, if there are NAs in the POSIX-lt variables, only `is.na()` can be used to drop rows with NAs.

I approximately know the difference between POSIX "ct" and "lt".

- `POSIXct` represents the number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 as a numeric vector.
- `POSIXlt` is a named list of vectors representing.

So someone can explain why `POSIXlt`'s missing values cannot be identified by `drop_na()` and `na.omit()` ?

Comment: See `?na.omit`: "At present [`na.omit`] will handle [...] data frames comprising vectors and matrices (only)." Thus, list columns, such as a `POSIXlt` column, will not be handled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: use POSIXct unless you really need POSIXlt

Longer answer:

POSIXlt is a difficult and capricious data structure. See:

```
> str(c(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()), NA))
 POSIXlt[1:2], format: "2018-10-07 00:43:06" NA
> unclass(c(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()), NA))
$sec
[1] 15.78872       NA

$min
[1] 43 NA

$hour
[1]  0 NA
# skipped a few rows

$isdst
[1]  1 -1

$zone
[1] "EEST" ""   
# skipped a few rows
```

In short, POSIXlt is a list of vectors, each vector representing one of the date/time units: seconds, minutes, hours, days, etc., but also time zone etc. There is no method for `na.omit` for POSIXlt, so `na.omit.default` is used, which does not know the specifics of `POSIXlt` class and treats it as an ordinary list.

```
> na.omit(list(NA,NA,NA))
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA
```

If you need a `na.omit` method for `POSIXlt`, you can write one. But if not really, it is easier to use `POSIXct`.

A corollary: `na.omit` doesn't really work with lists either (i.e., it can be used but does nothing). You can `sapply` or  `lapply` na.omit to the lists but that will produce strange results as well (`NA` components will be replaced by  `logical(0)`). It looks like `na.omit` is meant for use with atomic vectors or factors, as well as data frames. (The help page says, it's mostly useful with data frames). Which means that `na.omit` is not intended to be useful with lists, including `POSIXlt`.

Finally, why would one use POSIXlt at all? The idea (as far as i understand it) is that you can easily manipulate the date's components - but even that can produce unexpected results:

```
> foo <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
> foo
[1] "2018-10-07 01:06:22 EEST"
> foo$year
[1] 118
> foo$mon
[1] 9
> foo$mon <- 10
> foo
[1] "2018-11-07 01:06:22 EEST"
> foo$year <- 2018
> foo
[1] "3918-11-07 01:06:22 EEST"
```

So if you need to manipulate a date's components separately, you will have less surprises with lubridate.

```
> library(lubridate)
> year(foo)
[1] 3918
> year(foo) <- 2018
> foo
[1] "2018-11-07 01:06:22 EET"
> month(foo)
[1] 11
> month(foo)<-10
> foo
[1] "2018-10-07 01:06:22 EEST"
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation !

Comment: At the part you accounted for manipulating the date's components, I think the output is not unexpected. `foo$year` represents the number of year from 1900 and `foo$mon` stores 1~12 with 0~11. So that you assigned `foo$year` to 2018 actually means (1900+2018).